# Diagonalization of specific symmetric tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, tridiagonal-matrices

I am wondering if there is a way to get an explicit expression for the eigenvalues (and possibly the eigenvectors) of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix with the following peculiar structure:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & k\sqrt{1} & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
k\sqrt{1} & 1 & k\sqrt{2} & 0 & \dots \\
0 & k\sqrt{2} & 2 & k\sqrt{3} & \dots \\
0 & 0 & k\sqrt{3} & 3 & \dots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}
\right)
$$
in the limit where the size of the matrix goes to infinity.
The context of this problem is quantum physics, and by some arguments that are shown [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/770912/how-to-diagonalize-a-single-particle-hamiltonian/770923#comment1730514_770923), the answer should be something like $\lambda_n = n - k^2$.

I know that the characteristic polinomial can be written recursively as $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n(\lambda)$, where
$$
p_n(\lambda)=a_n(\lambda) p_{n-1}(\lambda) - b_{n-1}^2 p_{n-2}(\lambda),
\;\;\;\;\;
p_{0}(\lambda) = 1
\;\;\;\;\;
p_{-1}(\lambda) = 0,
$$
$a_n(\lambda)$ being the diagonal term, so $a_n=n-1-\lambda$ and $b_n$ being the off diagonal term, thus $b_n=k\sqrt{n}$, but I am stuck here.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, maybe there is a problem in the expression of your recursive expression because then $p_{n}(\lambda)$ does not depend on $\lambda$

Comment: Also, there is no general results for eigenvalues of infinite matrix, they should be seen as operator on the Hilbert space of sequences and thus have a residual, point and continuous spectrum

Comment: You are right, I missed a $-\lambda$ term, now I have edited my post. Yeah I know there are no general results, but in this specific case by phisical arguments you arrive to a simple result, that's why I am wondering if this specific problem can be solved somehow

Comment: I tried to compute the limit of $p_{n}(\lambda_{1})$ but it does not converge :( I’ll keep looking for any other values

Comment: I tried a numerical diagonalization for increasing sizes of the matrix, and in fact the difference between successive eigenvalues goes to 1

Comment: I also diagonalized the matrix for increasing values of $N_b$ (basis size) with some fixed value of $k$ (I chose $k=3.5$, but it doesn't matter), and computed the ratio $N_c/N_b$, where $N_c$ is the number of eigenvalues for which $|\lambda_n-(n-k^2)|>10^{-5}$. The ratio decreases with increasing $N_b$: more and more eigenvalues behave like $n-k^2$.